# Interference between newtxtext and ntheorem

Tags: packages, theorems, ntheorem, newtx

I tried using LaTeX after a long period of rest, and I found out that *newtxtext* and *ntheorem* collide with each other with the message 'Theoremstyle plain already defined'. On the other hand, *newtxmath* doesn't seem to interfere here.

```
\documentclass[openany,english]{scrbook}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{newtxtext}

\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb, graphicx}
\usepackage[amsmath, thmmarks, thref]{ntheorem}

\begin{document}

hello

\end{document}
```

I looked up the pdf documentations but couldn't find the reason; *ntheorem* documentation mentions about the possible interference with *amsmath*, with which I dealt correctly(hopefully), but nothing was mentioned about *newtxtext*. Same for the documentation for *newtxtext*; nothing was mentioned about *ntheorem*.

My question: what should I do in order to solve this collision? If I have to give up newtxtext(and possibly newtxmath), what fonts do you recommend in place of it that doesn't possibly collide with ntheorem?(I think it's too useful to give up...)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `newtxtext` loads `amsthm`. I don't think, that loading a theorem package inside a font package is a good idea, but it does.

Comment: @Taxxi - I am unable to replicate the issue you report, using either MacTeX2016 or MikTeX2.9. Please tell us which TeX distribution -- including its vintage -- you use.

Comment: @Mico I reinstalled MikTeX today so it's the latest version. I actually reproduced it right now one more time... I also have to mention I didn't have this problem before; it just happened today after a long break.

Comment: @Taxxi - I stand corrected! Somewhere between versions 1.5 and 1.515 (release date of the latter version: 2017/01/22) of `newtxtext` the instruction `\RequirePackage{amsmath,amsthm} % in case of theoremfont` made it into the package's code. (I just ran an update on my TeX distribution -- I had last done so about 10 days ago...) A bit unfortunate, to put it mildly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Package `newtxtext` loads `amsthm`. `amsthm` and `ntheorem` cannot be used together. The `ntheorem` manuals recommends to use option `amsthm` instead. So you have to prevent `newtxtext` from loading `amsthm`. Following seems to work:

```
\documentclass[openany,english]{scrbook}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,graphicx}
\usepackage[amsmath,amsthm,thmmarks,thref]{ntheorem}
\PreventPackageFromLoading{amsthm}
\usepackage{newtxtext}

\begin{document}

hello

\end{document}
```

It even seems to work without option `amsthm`.

If you do not use a KOMA-Script class, you have to load package `scrlfile` to get `\PreventPackageFromLoading`.

Comment: @Mico There is an unconditional `\RequirePackage{amsmath,amsthm}` in `newtxtext.sty` "just in case the user wants to specify `theoremfont`"

Comment: @AndrewSwann - Indeed, I just noticed this myself, after running an update on my system. (I had last done so 10 days ago.) I've posted a comment to this effect below the original posting.

Comment: You should mention the issue to the author of `newtx`; he's usually prompt to fix weaknesses in his package.

Comment: @egreg - Addendum 2017/01/31: As of version 1.516, dated 2017-01-30, of the `newtxtext` package, the OP's sample code no longer throws an error. The package now features an option called `theoremfont`. From the package's user guide: "The `theoremfont` option changes the default font used for the `plain` theoremstyle of `amsthm`, keeping italic
text but substituting upright figures and punctuation, and, provided you have loaded `theorem` or `amsthm`
before `newtxtext`, it will redefine the `plain` theoremstyle."